# Crystal report :splitted up in the launchpad

Tags: crystal-reports

Iam trying to open a report in launchpad..it is opening as pdf file. the report actually should open up in 3 pages but it is splitted and opened as 5 pages.  but when i try in crystal report 2016 it is opening fine.how to fix this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Crystal is probably rendering the report based on your default printer and page size.
Either change your default printer or set the report options to Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer page size (that's an option under File, Page Setup) for the report in Crystal Designer.